# SSL Let's encrypt certificate works only on default ports in nginx container (docker swarm)

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am running two docker swarm stacks on a single server (one for development and one for testing) - let's call them **dev and test**. Both are nearly identical - the only difference (beside ports) is that Nginx container in **test env** generates certificates with certbot and saves them to a volume, which is shared between both Nginx containers (**test and dev**). Nginx container in **test** has ports set to **443:443 and 80:80**, and Nginx container in **dev** is **8443:443** and **8080:80**. Now when I try to connect to **test** env and request https://example.com, everything works fine, but when I do the same with **dev** env and request https://example.com:8443 I get **NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**. The Nginx configs are the same between both containers. What might be the cause for this and how could I avoid it?

Also (I don't think it matters but still) when connecting to https://example.com:8443 I can see an only an error stating that this site uses hsts etc and I cannot see anything, but when I connect with https://ip:8443, I still get the warning, but I can see the page.

Comment: You can use the browser to look at the certificate details. The certificate name must match the URL (not the port number) of the service that you are connecting to. Do they match? If not, generate a certificate that has the correct name(s).

Comment: You've misconfigured the dev env somehow. The certificate doesn't know about ports, but your configuration does.

Comment: Alright, weird stuff. Today I tried to remove both stacks and set them up again without changing anything. This time it worked like a charm